# TypeError: props.onSaveExpenseData is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am leaning how to send data from child to parent component in React

Why I received this error: TypeError: props.onSaveExpenseData is not a function

Please help me because I am at learning phase and due to this error I am stuck on this and
I can't continue my further learning of next lectures.

Error shows in child component.

here github link of same file https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/blob/04-react-state-events/code/07-lifting-the-state-up/src/components/NewExpense/ExpenseForm.js

Here is Parent Component code with file name -NewExpense.js -

```
    import ExpenseForm from './ExpenseForm'
    import './NewExpense.css'
    
    function NewExpense () {
        const saveExpenseDataHandler = (enteredExpenseData)=> {
            const expenseData = {
                ...enteredExpenseData,
                id: Math.random().toString()
            };
    
            console.log(expenseData);
        } 
        return (
            <div className='expense-item'>
                <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default NewExpense;
```

and this is child component with file name ExpenseForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './ExpenseForm.css'

function ExpenseForm(props) {

  const [enteredTitle,setEnteredTitle] = useState('');
  const [enteredAmount,setEnteredAmount] = useState('');
  const [enteredDate,setEnteredDate] = useState('');

  const titleChangeHandler = (event) =>{
    setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);
    
  } 
  const amountChangeHandler = (event) =>{
    setEnteredAmount(event.target.value);
    
  }
  const dateChangeHandler = (event) =>{
    setEnteredDate(event.target.value);
    
  }
  
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const expenseData = {
      title: enteredTitle,
      amount: enteredAmount,
      date: new Date(enteredDate)
    };

    props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);  //here error arrives
    console.log(expenseData);

    setEnteredTitle('');
    setEnteredAmount('');
    setEnteredDate('');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div className='new-expense__controls'>
        <div className='new-expense__control'>
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text"
           value={enteredTitle}
           onChange={titleChangeHandler} />
        </div>
        <div className='new-expense__control'>
          <label>Amount</label>
          <input type="number" 
           value={enteredAmount}
           onChange={amountChangeHandler} min="0.01" step="0.01" />
        </div>
        <div className='new-expense__control'>
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" 
           value={enteredDate}
           onChange={dateChangeHandler} min="2020-01-01" max="2021-12-31" />
        </div>
        <div className='new-expense__actions'>
        <button type='submit'>Add Expense</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ExpenseForm;

~~~


  [1]: https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/blob/04-react-state-events/code/07-lifting-the-state-up/src/components/NewExpense/ExpenseForm.js
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code. Can you provide a small repo where you reproduce your issue?

Comment: Your code is just right, just dropped it into a Sandbox and works like a charm.
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-sea-q5t9y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/blob/04-react-state-events/code/07-lifting-the-state-up/src/components/NewExpense/ExpenseForm.js

Comment: I am getting error on clicking add expense button

Comment: Did you save all the files? Are you sure you don't use ExpenseForm somewhere else?

Comment: @mytro-krasnikov Yes saved all the files & I am sure I don't use ExpenseForm somewhere else

Comment: @ComputerTech Can You share the App.js code ? Everything looks fine here

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue, solution which worked for me is simple.
Make sure you have kept space on both sides of '='. After making changes it worked for me.
Replace your code line with below working code:-

```
<ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData = {saveExpenseDataHandler}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to Import NewExpense in app.js.

add `<NewExpense />`component in place of `<ExpenseForm />` in App.js .
it should look something like this

```
import NewExpense from "./Components/NewExpense";
function App(){
  return(
   <div>
     <NewExpense />
     */other data*/
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you change the app.js file  and add the components

```
<div>
  <NewExpense onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler} />
  <Expenses items={expenses} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is basically andrei course

so in the previous component ensure to copy the correct function, since I am following the exact steps per the course in the NewExpense.js file

```
<div className='new-expense'>
<ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler}></ExpenseForm>
</div>
```

Comment: this can be added here as child to parent component or you can directly add in the app.js component but then ensure to remove it from here

Comment: if either of the above does not work please check you function properly

Answer (score 0):

`import NewExpense from './components/NewExpense/NewExpense';`

just import the NewExpense.js file into your App.js file

Answer (score 0):

As per Maximilian course, you are doing the mistake in app.js. In app.js we have to use  instead on .
And make sure all the function name you copied properly.

```
**App.js**

import React from 'react';

import Expenses from './components/Expenses/Expenses';
import NewExpense from './components/NewExpense/NewExpense';

const App = () => {
  const expenses = [
    {
      id: 'e1',
      title: 'Toilet Paper',
      amount: 94.12,
      date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
    },
    { id: 'e2', title: 'New TV', amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
    {
      id: 'e3',
      title: 'Car Insurance',
      amount: 294.67,
      date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
    },
    {
      id: 'e4',
      title: 'New Desk (Wooden)',
      amount: 450,
      date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
    },
  ];

  // return React.createElement(
  //   'div',
  //   {},
  //   React.createElement('h2', {}, "Let's get started!"),
  //   React.createElement(Expenses, { items: expenses })
  // );

  return (
    <div>
      <NewExpense /> // use newexpense instead of expenseform
      <Expenses items={expenses} />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Cross the import statements and spelling of the method name.